# I want to get separate logs with date daily instaed of log getting overwritten in log4j2.xml

Tags: log4j2

I have code sample where I would get log generated daily but it gets overwritten on the previous day log. But I want separate log generated daily with log name along with date. What changes need to be made in the below log4j2.xml so that logs get generated daily as separate log and not gets overwritten.

The code is given below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration packages="com.zetvisions.webapp.logging">
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="FILE"
            fileName="${catalina:logs}/${catalina:contextPath}.log"
            filePattern="$${catalina:logs}/$${date:yyyy-MM}/$${catalina:contextPath}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}-%i.log.gz"
        >
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%d %-5p %t - %m (%F:%L)%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="7" modulate="true" />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="50 MB" />
                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10" />
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.zetvisions" level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="FILE" />
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="de.opendata" level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="FILE" />
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.apache.jsp" level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="FILE" />
        </Logger>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="FILE" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I have tried with by changing interval to 1 and also changed filename and pattern under Appenders

I want the log for example  log should generate as logname 01-08-2019 something like this daily with the generated day date. But now only logname log exists and it is getting overwritten.